# How is the AND/OR operator represented as in Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex, operators

I'm currently programming a vocabulary algorithm that checks if a user has typed in the word correctly. I have the following situation:
The correct solution for the word would be "part1, part2".
The user should be able to enter either "part1" (answer 1), "part2" (answer 2) or "part1, part2" (answer 3). 
I now try to match the string given by the user with the following, automatically created, regex expression:

```
^(part1|part2)$
```

This only returns answer 1 and 2 as correct while answer 3 would be wrong. I'm now wondering whether there's an operator similar to | that says `and/or` instead of `either...or`.

May anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Regular expressions might not be the best solution for this. I'd use normal string methods.

Comment: This problem is poorly specified. Why are you using pattern matching when all you need is an exact string comparison against a set of legal strings? Unless your regex compiler optimizes alternatives into an O(1) trie structure the way Perl’s does, you should probably be doing a test against hash membership instead. Other regex engines just aren’t very clever at this.

Comment: @tchrist The use case could be a mongodb `$or` regex match

Answer (score 389, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want to build a the regex dynamically to contain other words than part1 and part2, and that you want order not to matter. If so you can use something like this:

```
((^|, )(part1|part2|part3))+$
```

Positive matches:

```
part1
part2, part1
part1, part2, part3
```

Negative matches:

```
part1,           //with and without trailing spaces.
part3, part2, 
otherpart1
```

Comment: Note that "part1, part"1 will be also positive. Which is not always desirable

Comment: @dimaaan Did you misplace your quotes? "part1, part1" will be a match, but "part1, part" won't be. Though you're correct that such a scenario is not covered by this solution, for the application of the OP where he's checking if the test-string consists of words in a vocabulary, I believe he does want a positive match even when a word is repeated. The word will still be part of the vocabulary no matter how many instances of it you've got.

Comment: neither `"part1, part"1` nor `"part1, part1"` matched, you can check it [here](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/ef9650f1dea6).

Comment: @AmineKOUIS With 385 upvotes, don't you think it's likely that it does work as advertised? If you're attempting to match with quotes around it, that's not supposed to match. "part1, part1" without the quotes does match. Not sure how the site you linked to is supposed to work, cause it doesn't seem to match anything. I suggest you try this on regexr.com instead.

Answer (score 54):

```
'^(part1|part2|part1,part2)$'
```

does it work?

Comment: Obviously. the regex requires the whole string to match ( ^, $)

Comment: it didn't work for me, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/5d9903788543).

Answer (score 9):

Not an expert in regex, but you can do `^((part1|part2)|(part1, part2))$`. In words: "part 1 or part2 or both"

Answer (score 6):

Does this work without alternation?

```
^((part)1(, \22)?)?(part2)?$
```

or why not this?

```
^((part)1(, (\22))?)?(\4)?$
```

The first works for all conditions the second for all but `part2`(using GNU sed 4.1.5)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use this:

```
^(?:part[12]|(part)1,\12)$
```