# how to create a regex that has 2 possible conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi guys i'm wondering how to make a regex that doesnt allow spaces or numbers my current code works for numbers and space. I want numbers or spaces.

```
/([0-9])\s+/g
```

only works on numbers with spaces at the end, need it to work for numbers and spaces in any order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [and/or operator in regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020848/and-or-operator-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 3):

Include the space character in your square brackets:

```
[0-9\s]+
```

Or if you're looking for excluding spaces and numbers (\d means a digit, same as 0-9):

```
[^\d\s]+
```