# How to use regex OR operation in impala regex_extract method and get different capture group

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I have the following `table1` with attribute `co`:

```
|-----------------------------------------
| co
|-----------------------------------------
| fsdsdf "This one" fdsfsd ghjhgj "sfdsf"
| Just This 
|-----------------------------------------
```

In case there are quotation mark - I would like to get the first occurrence content. If there is no quotation mark I would like to return the content as is.
For the above example:
For the first line - `This one`
For the second line - `Just This` 
I have SQL code in Impala that solves the first case:

```
select regexp_extract (co, '"([^"]*")',1) from table1
```

How can I generalize it to detect and return the required results for the next case?

Comment: I guess you can use `COALESCE` or `IF()` in your sql, to return the hole string if not matched.

Comment: SQL isn't the best tool for doing this operation.  How did you end up having to scrub this data inside Impala?

Comment: The data is already in impala. I would like to use REGEX functionality and not the SQL functionality for the above since it is more efficient. I think the solution can use the OR expression in REGEX something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020848/and-or-operator-in-regular-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not generalize it in impala. As far as the problem you are having it requires OR | implementation in your regex. With regex_extract you need to put capture group no. in the end  . e.g.

`select regexp_extract (co, '"([^"]*")',`**1**`) from table1`

But with | operand in a regex, capture group will have to be different for both case. Which you can not define in your regex_extract method.

Say if **(A)**|**(B)** is your regex then for your first case capture group will be **1** and for your second case capture group will be **2** . But you can not put both 1 and 2 in your regex_extract syntax to date.

The Generic regex syntax would be (which i guess won't work in impala grouping):

```
^(?!.*")(.*)$|^[^"]*"(.*?)".*$
```

[Watch out the capture groupings](https://regex101.com/r/aqQaWg/2)

In the link , you will see **"This One"** is captured as group 2 
Where as **Just this** is captured as group 1

Answer (score 1):

Check This using union.

```
 select regexp_extract (co, '"([^"]*")',1) from table1
 union
 select co from table1 where co like '"%"'
```

Comment: That is not regex OR , isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if` function and put RegEx functions inside for the arguments. So,

```
if(regexp_like(co,'"'),
   regexp_extract(co,'"([^"]*)',1), co)
```