# Filtering Messages by fields

Tags: c++, pattern-matching, string-matching, fix-protocol

I want to find messages which are matched with a user define pattern using C++ Code.
The sample message is

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=70|35=A|34=1|49=SAM|52=20170124-02:55:47|56=SAM|98=0|108=300|141=Y|10=236|
```

This is FIX message.

I want to find out is a message is matched with user defined filter or not?

A sample filter is

```
(9=70 OR 35=A) AND 49=SAM
```

Is there any library for matching?
I would have to say that I can change the format of filter, but I need to support **AND, OR , = , ()**

Comment: So why aren't the normal C++ relational operators enough for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam!

I believe that you can use standard cpp regular expression [library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to solve this problem that way. 
And here is small [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020848/and-or-operator-in-regular-expression) how to build your AND/OR conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in this case, I am looking for a solution for parsing the filter. And there are several methods for parsing FIX messages.

Comment: Same regular expression library perfectly feet here too. Yes, it will be more sophisticated, comparable to the FIX parsing but still applicable.