# Issue while making number and char combination regex

Tags: regex

I am learning regex and I started my example with below exercise.

A regex with

> 1. Min one lower case.
> 2. Min one number

and I tried below and it works perfectly and already tested in regex exe.

```
^[0-9]+[a-z]+$
```

[image]

The only problem is: I can't write chars first and number after chars. I meant when I tried with example **a1**, it got failed

Can you please suggest? How can I write char first and then number using same regex

Comment: Try `(^[0-9]+[a-z]+$|^[a-z]+[0-9]+$)`. See [and/or operator in regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020848/and-or-operator-in-regular-expression)

Comment: @Irfan434 You above expression will not work for such string `ae11ss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)(?=\S+$).{8,}$
```

**Explanation**

```
^                 # start-of-string
(?=.*[0-9])       # a digit must occur at least once
(?=.*[a-z])       # a lower case letter must occur at least once
(?=.*[A-Z])       # an upper case letter must occur at least once
(?=.*\W)          # a special character must occur at least once
(?=\S+$)          # no whitespace allowed in the entire string
.{8,}             # anything, at least eight places though
$                 # end-of-string
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Regex Coach` supports `positive lookahead` then this will help you out.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nDvb69/1)

**Regex:** `^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z]).*`

> **1.** `^` start of string
>
> **2.** `(?=.*?\d)` positive look ahead for a digit
>
> **3.** `(?=.*?[a-z])` positive look ahead for a lowercase character `a-z`
>
> **4.** `.*` match all

Comment: `?=.*?` can you please explain the meaning of this thing?

Comment: `.*` is matches all because it is greedy, where as `.*?` makes this operator as lazy. `.*?[a-z]` match all till the first occurence of `a-z`

Comment: @Pankaj try this greedy one https://regex101.com/r/vVS8cZ/1/ and a lazy one https://regex101.com/r/uqD4KZ/1/

Comment: @Pankaj I think examples, in itself explain everything

Comment: if I need `Min one lower case` , `Min one number` and `Min one upper case` then I will need 9 possible combinations using this way. right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144192/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-pankaj).

Comment: @Pankaj I can help you with that as well.., we can discuss it over chat, for your above question you can check this https://regex101.com/r/nDvb69/3

Answer (score 0):

While Sahil Gulati's answer is generally the better option, a more intuitive alternative would be to simply use the regex logical 'or' (the `|` symbol):

```
^[0-9]+[a-z]+$|^[a-z]+[0-9]+$
```

This matches either

1. `^[0-9]+[a-z]+$`
2. `^[a-z]+[0-9]+$`

Comment: if I need Min `one lower case` , `Min one number` and `Min one upper case` then I will need 9 possible combinations using this way. right?