# RegEx to identify guid or a number

Tags: javascript, regex, match, guid

I have regex for guid:

> /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i

And regex to match a number:

> /^[0-9]*$

But I need to match either a guid or a number. Is there a way to do it matching a single regex. Or should I check for guid and number separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `|` in a regular expression to match either what comes before or what comes after:

```js
const re = /^([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12})|[0-9]+$/i;
console.log('11111111-1111-1111-8111-111111111111'.match(re)[0]);
console.log('5555'.match(re)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use | operator between two regex expressions. You can use them as given below

```
/(^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i) | (^[0-9]*$)/
```

Comment: Positioning of brackets seem to be wrong between the two OR conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many ways for this. One is to OR the matches in an `if` statement:

```
var reg1 = /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i;
var reg2 = /^[0-9]*$/;
var text = " ... ";

if (reg1.test(text) || reg2.test(text)) {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Another approach is [ORing in the RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020848/and-or-operator-in-regular-expression) itself:

```
var regex = /(^[0-9]*)|^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i;
var text = " ... ";

if (regex.test(text)) {
  // do your stuff here
}
```