# Python re.findall returns only first match

Tags: python-3.x, regex, findall, python-re

I'm somewhat stuck with this and didn't find a similar issue here.

I want to get a list of all the tag elements in the string like, e.g. `<a>` -> `a` or `</b>` -> `b`

```
import re

s = '<p><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm">Example Link</a></p>'
pat = r'<\s*(\w+)/?\s*.*>'
tags = re.findall(pat, s)
print(tags)
```

Here I get `['p']` as a result. If I change the `\w+` to `[a-d]+` I just get `['a']` as a result.

I'd expect as result `['p', 'a', 'a', 'p']` or at least all the distinct tag values.

What did I do wrong here? Thank you!

Using Python 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make your pattern match non-greedy (switch `.*` to `.*?`). You can read more about that in the examples given in the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) (they even use HTML tags as an example!).

Secondly, the `/?` part should be at the start, rather than after the tag name `\w+`.

Also, the second `\s*` is redundant, since `.*` will capture whitespaces as well.

```
import re

s = '<p><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm">Example Link</a></p>'
pat = r'</?\s*(\w+).*?>'
tags = re.findall(pat, s)
print(tags)
```

Output:

```
['p', 'a', 'a', 'p']
```

For a much more general solution, consider using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) instead:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class HTMLTagParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        tags.append(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        tags.append(tag)

s = '<p><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm">Example Link</a></p>'
tags = []
parser = HTMLTagParser()
parser.feed(s)
print(tags)
```

Output:

```
['p', 'a', 'a', 'p']
```

The approach will work arbitrary HTML (since regex can become messy as you minimize assumptions made). Note, for start tags, the `attrs` argument in `handle_starttag` can also be used to retrieve the attributes of the tag, should you need them.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The string is just an example, there can also be '/' after the tag characters if these are self-closing tags. One question: why the .*?    -  I thought .* matches 0 or more of any character. I don't really understand the ? here.

Comment: Great, I also update my answer to include an alternative using Python modules, which is a more general and reliable solution than using regex.

Comment: @matt444 Its regex syntax for making the the `.*` non-greedy. You can read more about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) in the Python docs -- they even use HTML tags as an example.

Answer (score 0):

use the or (|) operator and write down both the patterns separated by an operator, it should work.

refer to this,
[How is the AND/OR operator represented as in Regular Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020848/how-is-the-and-or-operator-represented-as-in-regular-expressions)